# How can I append or add rows below the last row. (in worksheet)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

It is possible to append a row in a table using the method below:

```
POST /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables/{id|name}/rows/add
```

How can I do the same but in a worksheet?

Now it's only possible to Update with a specific range:

```
PATCH /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')
```

I can't type in the address like "range(address='A(lastRow):C(lastRow)')"

Comment: Give a try adding table with a max range for row and column and use the first call `/tables/name/rows/add` to add rows to table.

Comment: Sorry @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I didn't undestand your suggestion. Working with a table inside a worksheet, it is possible to append a row. But I don't want to work with table, only with worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the last row number using an Excel function(Match) before appending the row.

```
POST /me/drive/root:/demo.xlsx:/workbook/functions/match
```

BODY

```
{
    "lookupvalue": "",
    "lookuparray": {
        "Address": "sheet1!A:A"
    },
    "matchtype": -1
}
```

Specify the last row number as the range and update the value.